# Android how to combine two parse queries using 'OR'

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am looking to combine two parse queries into one which satisfies an 'OR' condition. How do I achieve this? The docs say that I need a list of parse queries but I am not very sure how to do that ?
Here is my code :

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> numberQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
        numberQuery.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", currentUser.getObjectId());
        numberQuery.whereContainedIn("phoneNumber", values);
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> emailQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
        emailQuery.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", currentUser.getObjectId());
        numberQuery.whereContainedIn("email", values);
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> superQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
        superQuery.or
```

How do I complete this query and get the 'OR' of the two in superquery ?
Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Okay I figured it out myself. To create a list you use

```
    List<ParseQuery<ParseUser>> queries = new ArrayList<ParseQuery<ParseUser>>();
```

and then

```
queries.add(q1);
queries.add(q2);
```

and so on.
And then you use

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> superQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
        ParseQuery.or(queries);
```

to get the final combined query.